# Suggestions about 2D in a "risk"-like game for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

The idea of programming a risk-like game for iOS has been around my mind for more than a week, so I thought I should do something about it. I'm not an experienced iOS developer (I haven't done a real project, only tutorials), but I got some notions about both the language and Cocoa Touch.

So, the thing I want to do is a board game, similar to dicewars (see http://www.gamedesign.jp/flash/dice/dice.html). The maps will at some point have hexagonal-tiles, but if it is to much pain for starters, I don't have a problem with regular tiles for the beginning. I want the maps to be dynamically generated, not made in advance. There won't be much on the game screen : the map, divided in areas, the dices, and a HUD.

The main thing I'm grasping with right now is what to use to do the graphic stuff. I have no background in game programming, and very limited in 2D. For my purposes, should I go with Core Graphics/Animation, OpenGL, Cocos2D, or something else ? I would like to avoid starting with a technology, and halfway through the project, realizing another would have be more adapted.

I'm also listening to any advice about game dev in general, map generation, IA programming.. etc. If you have links that answers my question, feel free, I haven't found anything conclusive so far

**tl;dr:**

I'm wondering how should I do 2D for a simple board game similar to dicewars/risk. No need for collision stuff, just something to draw a map, update it, and display a hud.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest Cocos2d:  Very easy to get started, has more than enough functionality to cover your requirements (including tile-maps built into the engine), has an active community, and has been the framework used by many successful games.